# Symfony CLI commands and Compiler pass

Tags: php, command, command-line-interface, symfony

I just want to know how to get all my commands Symfony services into my compiler pass ?

Is there a mean to find services by implemented interfaces ? Or perhaps i have to tag them all ?

Thanks,
KL.

Comment: This might help: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/02/12/drop-all-service-tags-in-your-nette-and-symfony-applications/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382545/implementing-strategy-pattern-symfony-4-with-compiler-pass-is-broken-for-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tag them all. There is no way to retreive services which are instance of some expected class/interface.

Anyway, you can just get all, iterate over them, and filter only those which extends your interface. But it's much slower, and the most awful way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you question correctly. If you're trying to get all commands defined in your application then:

```
    $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $commands = $application->all('doctrine');
    var_dump($commands);die;
```

This example with a fresh symfony install you can fetch all doctrine commands. Just replace 'doctrine' with your commands prefix.

Take a look in \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application especially registerCommands method. I'm using latest version Symfony 3.2.4