# Implementing Strategy pattern Symfony 4 with Compiler pass is broken for me

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.2

I implement the strategy pattern using Symfony 4.2 and the issue is the addMethodCall in the following isn't executed.

```
class ConverterPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{ 
    const CONVERSION_SERVICE_ID = 'crv.conversion';
    const SERVICE_ID = 'crv.converter';

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // check if the conversion service is even defined
        // and if not, exit early
        if ( ! $container->has(self::CONVERSION_SERVICE_ID)) {
            return false;
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition(self::CONVERSION_SERVICE_ID);

        // find all the services that are tagged as converters
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(self::SERVICE_ID);

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tag) {
            // add the service to the Service\Conversion::$converters array
            $definition->addMethodCall(
                'addConverter',
                [
                    new Reference($id)
                ]
            ); 
        }
    } 
}
```

In kernel.php I got 
        protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
        {
            $container->addCompilerPass(
                new ConverterPass()
            );
        }

My ConverterInterface.php

```
namespace App\Converter;

interface ConverterInterface
{
    public function convert(array $data);
    public function supports(string $format);
}
```

then ConvertToSela.php and similarly another Convert

```
namespace App\Converter;


class ConvertToSela implements ConverterInterface
{
    public function supports(string $format)
    {
        return $format === 'sela';
    }

    public function convert(array $data)
    {
        return 'sela';
    }
}
```

In Conversion.php which I execute I get empty array which means the addConverter isn't called.

```
class Conversion
{

    private $converters;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->converters = [];
    }

    public function addConverter(ConverterInterface $converter)
    {
        dd($converter);
        $this->converters[] = $converter;

        return $this->converters;
    } 

    public function convert(array $data, $format)
    {
        foreach ($this->converters as $converter) {
            if ($converter->supports($format)) {
                return $converter->convert($data);
            }
        }

        throw new \RuntimeException('No supported Converters found in chain.');
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/954o/implementing-tagged-strategy-pattern-services-with-symfony-compiler-pass-feature

Comment: That’s very similar to my code. Perhaps it works with older version of Symfony?

Comment: It works with S4.

Comment: You are making your life harder by trying to use compiler pass for what you are trying to do. Just stick with Symfony's tagged services. This is a full example and all you will do is rename things. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/tznl/implementing-tagged-strategy-pattern-services-without-symfony-compiler-pass-feature

Comment: Thanks, for last comment. Looks more simple than I thought still I would like to know where is the problem in the original one. I'll copy the code of the link you sent and give it a go when I got sometime later today.

Comment: Thanks @BentCoder I found my problem. I posted an answer. Your code helped me to find that the service id I used with **findDefinition** was incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Working example on **Symfony 4.2.4** with [tagged services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html) and [compiler pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html):

**\App\Service\Strategy\FileContext:**

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service\Strategy;

class FileContext
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $strategies;

    /**
     * @param FileStrategyInterface $strategy
     */
    public function addStrategy(FileStrategyInterface $strategy): void
    {
        $this->strategies[] = $strategy;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function read(string $type): string
    {
        /** @var FileStrategyInterface $strategy */
        foreach ($this->strategies as $strategy) {
            if ($strategy->isReadable($type)) {
                return $strategy->read();
            }
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('File type not found');
    }
}
```

**\App\Service\Strategy\FileStrategyInterface:**

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service\Strategy;

interface FileStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isReadable(string $type): bool;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function read(): string;
}
```

**\App\Service\Strategy\CsvStrategy:**

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service\Strategy;

class CsvStrategy implements FileStrategyInterface
{
    private const TYPE = 'csv';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isReadable(string $type): bool
    {
        return self::TYPE === $type;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function read(): string
    {
        return 'Read CSV file';
    }
}
```

**\App\Service\Strategy\TxtStrategy:**

```php
class TxtStrategy implements FileStrategyInterface
{
    private const TYPE = 'txt';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isReadable(string $type): bool
    {
        return self::TYPE === $type;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function read(): string
    {
        return 'Read TXT file';
    }
}
```

**\App\DependencyInjection\Compiler\FileContextCompilerPass:**

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use App\Service\Strategy\FileContext;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class FileContextCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $service = $container->findDefinition(FileContext::class);

        $strategyServiceIds = array_keys($container->findTaggedServiceIds('strategy_file'));

        foreach ($strategyServiceIds as $strategyServiceId) {
            $service->addMethodCall('addStrategy', [new Reference($strategyServiceId)]);
        }
    }
}
```

**\App\Kernel:**

```php
namespace App;

use App\DependencyInjection\Compiler\FileContextCompilerPass;
...

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;
...
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new FileContextCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Make sure you've added valid taged services definitions.

**config/services.yaml:**

```yaml
    App\Service\Strategy\TxtStrategy:
        tags:
            - { name: strategy_file }

    App\Service\Strategy\CsvStrategy:
        tags:
            - { name: strategy_file }
```

Command for testing.
**\App\Command\StrategyCommand:**

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Command;

use App\Service\Strategy\FileContext;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class StrategyCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected static $defaultName = 'strategy:run';

    /**
     * @var FileContext
     */
    private $fileContext;

    /**
     * @param FileContext $fileContext
     */
    public function __construct(FileContext $fileContext)
    {
        $this->fileContext = $fileContext;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Run strategy example')
            ->addOption('file', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if (!$file = trim($input->getOption('file'))) {
            return;
        }

        echo $this->fileContext->read($file);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```bash
$ bin/console strategy:run --file=txt
Read TXT file%
$ bin/console strategy:run --file=csv
Read CSV file%
```

Comment: Please describe why this answers the question by explaining your solution ([How do I write a good answer?
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))

Comment: I'm not sure there is more to explain This is fully working POC which describe itself :) There are few small steps to do: create strategies and tag them, create strategies handler, create and register compiler pass. I had the same problem which I finally managed to work so I share with other.

Comment: @Marcin Harasim Are using both tagged services and compiler pass at same time or am I seeing it wrong?!

Comment: @BentCoder yes, you see it right :) For simple cases you don't have to write your own compiler pass which is described in [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html). You can and IMO you have to write compiler pass for more complex cases or you think your code will grow. For me it's more readable with tagged services and compiler pass.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in class **ConverterPass** when instead of the service id from **services.yaml** I have the class name it works fine.